# Como vincular os Id's de duas API's com ANGULAR?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Pessoal estou com um problema, e sou meio leigo com `Angular`.. tenho 2 funções que consultam dois métodos de uma `API`.. preciso comparar os `id's` dos resultados e demonstrar apenas as que o id for igual, Agradeço desde já! tenho o seguinte código:

```
function SearchDespesa(response){
  $this.Despesa = response;
  $this.Despesa.DespesaId; // Aqui retorna um json com as informações..

  // Daqui em diante não sei oque fazer
}

function SearchTipoDespesa(response){
  $this.TipoDespesa = response;
  $this.Despesa.EmpresaId; // Aqui retorna um json com as informações..

  // Daqui em diante não sei oque fazer
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta percorrer um dos dois `arrays`, e fazer a comparação, vou demostrar em `javascript` mas em `angular` você só vai acrescentar o `$scope`

```js
var dados = [
  {id: 1, nome: 'teste'},
  {id: 2, nome: 'teste2'},
];

var tipos = [
 {id: 1, tipo: 'carro'},
  {id: 2, tipo: 'musica'},
 {id: 3, tipo: 'bola'},
];

var resul = [];

for(var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
   if(tipos[i].id === dados[i].id) {
     resul.push(Object.assign(dados[i],tipos[i]));
   }
}

console.log(resul);
```

Comment: Vlw brother, sua ideia me ajudou a implementar o script, agradeço!